# Cache Protobuf-Net classes to Redis

Tags: redis, protobuf-net

I'm using the magic Protobuf-net in .NET7 and want to add Redis to do key-based Set/Get caching of medium-sized Json ProtoContract objects. Probably the best way is to protbuf-binary serialize the objects in and out of Redis? I found this https://riptutorial.com/stackexchange-redis/example/5218/complex-data--protobuf- and this https://easycaching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Features/

Any examples or tips available?... since with EasyCaching the configuration as show in the example is not finding the serializer:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'serializers')
at EasyCaching.Core.ArgumentCheck.NotNullAndCountGTZero[T](IEnumerable`1 argument, String argumentName)
at EasyCaching.Redis.DefaultRedisCachingProvider..ctor(String name, IEnumerable`1 dbProviders, IEnumerable`1 serializers, 
RedisOptions options, RedisLockFactory factory, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
```

Comment: You might want to try [redis-protobuf](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-protobuf), if you don't want to save serialized data into Redis. Declaimer: I'm the author of redis-protobuf.

Comment: Thanks. Saw this -> No .net client which is a turn-off for me.  Works with protobuf-net (how?).  I'll take another look since EasyCaching is not yet working for me.

Comment: Have you called `WithProtobuf` ? https://github.com/dotnetcore/EasyCaching/blob/6512d1c0b90d3f8ef8c59ef9d6a93c80417b09e5/docs/ProtoBuf.md?plain=1#L27

Comment: Thanks! Thought I had that covered by appsettings. Works without via MemoryStream as done here https://riptutorial.com/stackexchange-redis/example/5218/complex-data--protobuf- . Do I need that step for perf or is that being handled by EasyCaching?